# Zend Framework - No data received

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, apache2.4

I am working on Zend Framework, version 1.11 and I ran into the following problem:
After submitting a form, the browser yields "No data received: Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data." (on chrome) and "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." on firefox.
Now, has probably something to do with my machine, since I could not reproduce the error on other machines with similar configuration, save for the server version (I have upgraded to apache 2.4.7, the others have apache 2.2).
Now the code the request is going through is:

```
$form = new Website_Form_ArtUpload();
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
        {
            $response = $this->_getService()->upload($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            My_Logger::log(print_r($response));
            if (!$response->isValid()) {
                if($response->getData() instanceof Zend_Form) {
                    $form = $response->getData();
                }
                if($response->hasMessages()) {
                    My_Logger::log(print_r($response->getAllMessages()));
                    $this->view->messages = $response->getAllMessages();
                }
            }  else {
                $this->_helper->redirector->gotoSimple('new', 'product', 'website');
                return;
            }
        }
```

**content of $this->_getService()->upload()**

```
// Validate the form
    $form = new Website_Form_ArtUpload();
    if (!$form->isValid($data))
        return new My_Service_Response(
            My_Service_Response::FAILURE,
            $form,
            array(My_Model_Message::MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR => $this->getTranslator()->_('The product cannot be uploaded'))
        ); //here it halts
```

So, for once, I have no idea why the data shouldn't be valid as everything seems ok with it. But supposing the data is indeed invalid, since the response is a failure and there are messages (`$this->view->messages = $response->getAllMessages()` logs the message), I don't get why there isn't just a nice error saying 'the product could not be uploaded'.

If you need any other bits of code, or any logs, I'm happy to provide them.

Notes: other forms with errors return the messages properly.
Please don't tell me we should have the same server version, I know that, but if sometime in the future we want to migrate to 2.4, we'd rather have this solved already.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the image validation MIME type, file size.. etc.

```
if (!$form->isValid($data)) {
...
}
```

This issue is fixed in latest Zend Framework 1.12.9 you can just download the latest version from 
https://packages.zendframework.com/releases/ZendFramework-1.12.9/ZendFramework-1.12.9.zip

if you don’t need to update the full framework, just replace the all files from 
" library -> Zend -> Validate -> File" with the latest files from the ZendFramework-1.12.9

Make sure that you test all the pages after the update